# How can I loop back to main() after using exec() system call?

Tags: c++, unix

For a Unix class, we have to recreate the shell `|` pipe redirection ability using `fork()`, `pipe()`, `exec()`. I am able to do so, but we have to now implement the whole program in a loop so that once the user is done, they can do it again. How do I go back to the beginning of the program? The trouble is that the `exec()` system call completely replaces the current running executable. How can I get back to main() in my program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char command1[127];
    char command2[127];

    char* token1[5];
    char* token2[5];

    int pipefd[2],
        i = 0;

    pid_t rs, fs;

    // Get two commands from users.

    cout << "Enter command 1 along with any arguments: ";
    cin.getline(command1, 127);

    string comString1 = command1;
    if (comString1 == "quit")
        exit(1);

    cout << "Enter command 2 along with any arguments: ";
    cin.getline(command2, 127);

    string comString2 = command2;
    if (comString2 == "quit")
        exit(1);

    // Parse both commands into tokens.

    token1[i] = strtok(command1, " ");
    while (token1[i] != NULL) {
        i++;
        token1[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    i = 0;

    token2[i] = strtok(command2, " ");
    while (token2[i] != NULL) {
        i++;
        token2[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Create pipe.

    rs = pipe(pipefd);

    if (rs < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    // First fork. There are now two processes.

    rs = fork();

    if (rs < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (rs == 0) { // Child
        close(pipefd[1]);

        close(0);

        dup(pipefd[0]);

        close(pipefd[0]);

        // Second fork. There are now three processes.

        fs = fork();

        // Trouble begins here I reckon. I forked once and forked again in a child. That may be an issue here.

        if (fs == 0) { Child
            rs = execlp(token2[0], token2[0], token2[1], token2[2], token2[3], token2[4], NULL);
            if (rs < 0) {
                perror("execlp in child");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else { // Parent
            // This execl() functions runs, but runs over and over. Am I infinitely forking processes and thus calling execl() infinitely?
            execl("/home/hopper/z1806979/csci330/Assign4/Assign4", "Assign4", NULL); 
        }
    }
    else { // Parent

        close(pipefd[0]);

        close(1);

        dup(pipefd[1]);

        close(pipefd[1]);

        rs = execlp(token1[0], token1[0], token1[1], token1[2], token1[3], token1[4], NULL);

        if (rs < 0) {
            perror("execlp in parent");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags! This is not realted to C. 2) Learn [ask].

Comment: Thanks for input. I removed c flag.

Comment: 1) It's a _tag_ 2) No, I already removed it. 3) Concentrate on improving the question.

Answer (score 0):

`exec` is a system call that recover the current code of the current process calling `exec` with the code contained in the specified file. I suspect that you are constantly recovering a code by itself and that you are recovering your "shell" with some input command (that should not be).

You also should notice that after recovering there is NO WAY to get back into the previous code... Recovering, recovers.